# Vectors in three dimensions and two unknown components

Tags: vectors

Given vector $\vec{v} = (\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{3}, a)$ and vector $\vec{w} = (1, b, -1)$, I am supposed to find a real number for a and b such that the two vectors $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{w}$ are orthogonal/perpendicular. I know that the dot product should equal 0, but how do I determine a and b from that?

It looks like to me that this question could have multiple solutions for a and b, but I cant find a simple method of determining this without guessing the numbers...

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: choose any values of $a$ and $b$ which satisfy $\frac14+\frac13b-a=0$. Obviously there are infinitely many solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual inner product on $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ is given by:
$$\langle v, w \rangle := v_{1}w_{1}+v_{2}w_{2}+v_{3}w_{3}$$
where $v = (v_{1},v_{2},v_{3})$ and $w= (w_{1},w_{2},w_{3})$. In your case:
$$\langle v, w \rangle = \frac{1}{4}+\frac{b}{3}-a.$$
As you mentioned, in order to $v$ and $w$ to be orthogonal we must have:
$$\langle v, w \rangle = 0$$
so that any $a$ and $b$ satisfying:
$$\frac{1}{4}+\frac{b}{3}-a = 0$$
fulfills the condition. We have infinitely many answers and you can pick any of such solutions as the solution of your problem.